# Reserving a id(pk) in sqlite for a entry

Tags: django, sqlite, django-forms, primary-key

I'm a beginner and the doubt might be silly
Have a doubt if I can reserve an auto generated id in sqlite table while trying to register the fields through a form

The Problem faced is 
I am relying on the **'id'** as my primary key which for next entry i **manually calculate** counting the nuber of **existing entries in db + 1**

If I open the same form from **2 different browsers simultaneously** both get the **same id**.
The data held in DB is contents of the form that is submitted later of the two.
I want both the entries to be updated to DB.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you manually calculating the ID instead of letting the database do it?

Comment: Just so I understand, you _are_ currently using the SQLITE auto generated ID and _that's_ getting dupes in the db? Or you're getting dupes with a manually generated one and thinking of switching to the SQLITE auto generated one to solve.

Comment: ID should be created by database. If your table is correctly created, just add new rows without supplying ID (or supplying NULL).

Comment: Not very sure of how to make auto increement using django sqlite. And would using autoincreement solve the issue?

Comment: I am using SQLITE **autogenerated ID** as **pk**. Now for a new entry,I want to **display the entry number** so for that I fetch the current count and add one to it and dsiplay and pass this as the parameter. If 2 forms are opened simultaneously before the 1st is submitted both get the same number.

Comment: user1007839, the change would be on the DB table definition. take a look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_autoincrement.htm

Comment: OK, that was useful information that should have been in your post (you should edit it and add it). But you still have not explained why you need the new (incremented) ID in your form at all. Why not just save the newly created object and let the db assign the id?

Comment: Like I mentioned that before the object is saved I want the user to know the id that is being generated for the post. Hence maually calculating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to be rude, but trying to reserve an ID, especially one that is a primary key, is flawed logic at best.

An easier approach to "reserve" the ID would be to simply create the record, and get the ID back at the beginning of your workflow.

Any subsequent functionality in your workflow would just be updating the record you initially created.

This way you can create the record, effectively "reserving" it, show it to the end user and then continue to add information to the model per your workflow.

If the workflow is abandoned for some reason, just delete the record.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. Totally agree with you with the flaw of db design. I was to work on an existing database which was designed with pk being the id. Did not want to make changes to the db.
Changed the way to reserve id, not a good approach i suppose but works for the time being. Thanks again